# Action when string is wrote somewhere

Tags: autohotkey

is it possible to operate action when string is wrote somewhere (Auto Hot key).
For example, When I will write the word "HELLO", action will operate. Then:

```
if (stringWrote == "HELLO"){
//WILL DO SOMETHING }
```

Comment: See [Hotstrings and Auto-replace](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Use Hotstrings:

```
:*:HELLO::
    ; do sth
return
```

Also refer to the documentation https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm , the beginner tutorial is really good.